# storing key in session variable

Tags: php, session

Hello guys i have seen a code which confuses me a lot..The code is

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'online');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

function SignIn()
{
    session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && $_POST['password'])   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM users where email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password']))
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['password'];
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
            header('Location: basicinfo.html');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: form.html');
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    SignIn();
}

if(isset($_POST['createAccount']))
{
    header('Location:create.html');
}
?>
```

Am a lot confused by seeing the code  `$_SESSION['email'] = $row['password'];` here i know The  `$row['password']`  get stored to `$_SESSION['email']` ..In `$row['password']` i know password is the key there ..

My question is that what will be the corresponding value of the key "password" from `$row['password']` ..Is the value fetched from the query ?? ..Am stucked with this.

Please help me ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks

Comment: Did you write this code on your own or you found it somewhere online? If you found it online, can you please give us the link to that script or whatever it is? Without wanting to sound rude, this is one the worst pieces of shit of code I've seen this year.

Comment: This code will put your password in the session variable. Clearly not what you want! And if you want to know the value, just var_dump() it. :)

Comment: @nb ..found online ..lol

Comment: so ...the value of the corresponding key "password" will be fetched from the query ?..right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$row['password'] will contain the password the query returned from the database.

Also your code is completly open for sql injections.

Comment: so ...the value of the corresponding key password will be fetched from the query ?..right ?

Comment: is this only used with the function mysql_fetch_array ?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['email']` and `$row['password']` will contain result of the query with the key password

Comment: so ...the value of the corresponding key password will be fetched from the query ?..right ?

Comment: Yes, it is the the value of the corresponding key password will be fetched from the query. can you tell me what exactly is your requirement ?